# Google datastore backup to local dev_appserver

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, dev-appserver, appcfg

I'm trying to follow those instructions: https://gist.github.com/jehna/3b258f5287fcc181aacf

I've downloaded my backup, made the script go to the path but it seems like the code won't get into the loop "for record in reader:" on windows. I read about it and from my impression it has to do with to format of the file (leveldb) which is not supported in windows that good. 
Do you have any insights/solutions about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code work on windows when chaging file openning permissions from 'r' to 'rb' in windows

Comment: This no longer seems to work even after making this change.

Comment: Are you using the exact code? please paste to me the code that you're using exactly and which OS are you trying to run on so I could look it up

Comment: Yeah, I used the code exactly (both with 'r' and 'rb'). It never enters the `for record in reader` loop. I'm on Windows 10. I've given up on using this and moved on to a custom way to export/import the data.