# App Engine: Copy live Datastore to local Dev Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is a question that has been answered many times however the answer seems to always change.

I am working in Windows using Java and have a local Datastore instance that I would like to be a replica of production.

There is two previous answers:-

[How to create local copy of GAE datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671438/how-to-create-local-copy-of-gae-datastore)

[App Engine: Copy live Datastore to local dev Datastore (that still works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063925/app-engine-copy-live-datastore-to-local-dev-datastore-that-still-works)

However both seem to be out of date.  Can anyone at the least point me in the right direction?

Comment: instead of posting the same question again, post a bounty on the existing question(s) with the reason "Current answers are outdated"

Answer (score 4):

You could try to switch to the Datastore Emulator instead of using the emulation from the development server (which should work with the recent local development server versions, at least the ones packed in the gcloud SDK) and then you'd be able to use the official method of importing the data in the emulator, see [Importing Entities Into Local GCP Datastore Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717445/importing-entities-into-local-gcp-datastore-emulator).

Comment: Specifically, the documentation to import into the emulator is at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import .